# when try open my project in javafx by web browser give me message for security recommended

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, java-web-start

I have some issue when I open my project build it by javafx and when I try to open it by browser it's give message as like: it's most be as high security?
I try everything I open java config on the control panel as following picture:

[image]

then when I run the project is showing this message

[image]

[image]

please if you have any solving for this issue show me 
thanks...

Comment: "_...with an out-of-date or expired version of Java_". I see you are using Java 8u161; have you tried updating to the latest Java 8 version?

Comment: Hi dear @slaw no i didn't try yes i'm using Java 8u161

Comment: Well the latest version of Java 8 is update 181. Try updating to see if it works then.

Comment: Dear i updated but still the same issue